# StackOverFlowException: Value is either too small or too large for int 32 in MS TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, stack-overflow

I have created a simple application with MS `TextBox` control and DataBinding has been done to the `TextBox`. If I try to enter the `double` value into the `TextBox`, then I got

> “StackOverFlowException: Value is either too large or too small for Int32” .

Here is my code:

**Form1.cs**

```
DataBinding db = new DataBinding();
this.dataBindingBindingSource.DataSource = db;
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataBindingBindingSource, "Number", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

**DataBinding.cs**(My Own class)

```
class DataBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int number=4;
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
        set
        {
            number = value;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me whether how can we overcome this exception?

Answer (score 0):

The `Number` property you've defined is of type `int`, but you've entered a number into the bound text box that is either too small or too large to fit in an `int`. Therefore, it cannot be set in the `Number` property. Thus, the code throws an exception.

What would you expect it to do? We cannot tell you how to fix it. Some possible options are:

- increase the bit width of the field/property by choosing a type larger than `int`, thus ensuring that larger values can be represented
- handle the exception and round/truncate the value entered by the user so that it does fit into an `int`
- add validation code (that would run before data binding is attempted) in order to prevent the user from entering a value that is too large to fit into an `int`